# Microphone technology for noisy environment

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, field-recording

I am looking for a microphone that would allow me to record my voice in a noisy place where I can't control the environment. Think recording your voice while cycling in a big city as a voice over for a video.

I looked into throat microphones (aka laryngophones) but my impression is that the sound recorded is so garbled that it's not really usable for anything beyond very simple sound bits (see for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34WX3o2uBhI) or [there](https://youtu.be/nodTZG0eP9Q?t=207)). My understanding is that it's not just a matter of price, the technology is just limited that way.

Is there any other technology for microphones that would fit these criteria? The voice quality doesn't have to be fantastic, but it needs to come out clearly over the background noise and wind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wind noise is one problem which has been broadly solved through wind shields (Google Dead Cat by Rode or similar)

Once that is solved, noise cancelling microphones work pretty well - a prime example would be the microphones pilots use. They are effective in noisy environments. They don't get rid of all noise, but they dramatically improve the noise floor such that voice is really heard and understood.

Comment: Is this what you are referring to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-canceling_microphone

Comment: Yes - there are many on the market.